# JavaScript in SQL

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I have to insert a new primary key in my sqldb each time the year changes( eg: year 2012 my key its 2012000000, year 2013 my key will be 2013000000) and i want to do it automatically

My approach is to add a script to the admin panel like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.php"></script>
```

What i want to know:

- Can i insert an arbitrary value to a primary key if it is a auto increment ?
- if so, will it auto increment with no problems?
- Is my overall approach correct?

Comment: You should specify which sql db you are using... is it MySQL?

Comment: Not sure what you are after as the question seems a bit vague to me, but surely you can generate the year dynamically from your PHP script without the need for javascript.

Comment: Mixing different kinds of information in one column is never a good idea, I would strongly recommend adding a separate column for the year.

Comment: Your way of "thinks" isn't good sadly, use a different column for a year.

Comment: i just want to find a way to do this: i have this id 2012000123 and i want to change it to 2013000000

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of perverse approach.

1. Why do you need inserting the primary key at all? Have a look at [table partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29), it might achieve your goal much more elegantly.
2. If this limitation is implied by your application level (something like `year = primary_key / 1000000`) - consider reimplementing it, it is a huge design flaw.
3. If I'm not getting something and you are still sure you have to insert the ids - it depends on your database engine. Some of them allow for insertion of primary keys, hovewer require special syntax. Please specify the database you are using.
4. The proper way to achieve timed execution is using [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (if your server is running on *nix) or [Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) (if it's under Windows command). These are flexible tools for repeated execution. In your case you'll just tell it to run your script (`myscript.php`) at 00:00:00 01/01 each year - and you are fine. The script might be php page, console program or whatever.
5. One last point, why to heck it's javascript? The 'right' way would be to use `include`.

All in all, I strongly suggest rethinking on it. THe approach you end up last time is quite counter-intuitive and obvious, and buggy (just imagine what if nobody log in into the admin backend when time has come to add new year :))

Comment: my db file extension its (.db)

Comment: This tells me nothing. .db is used [widely](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/db). Most likely it's SQLite, but you'd better check it out yourself.

Comment: i want to change the id from "2012######" to "2013######" because the id its the number of a ticket. and i want to change it so i can know how many tickets i get every year eg: in 2011 this its my last ticket id "2011005061"

Comment: how can i know what type of db i have?

Comment: Your methods does not suit your goal at all. Table partitioning. Additional `year` field. New database each year. Whatever, but not incrementing the primary key. Regarding the database: it is quite outside of the scope of this question. Search SO or google for it.

Comment: i dont want the change the year i just want to change the id from "2012000518" to "2013000000"

Comment: After hearing your goal I'm absolutely sure you are doing it wrong. It's absolutely inappropriate way and you refuse using more elegant and robust solution. Have you come here for an answer `what should I write so it works my way` or `how should I achieve this goal`? If it's first - I can't help you.

Comment: ok. can you tell me how can i do should i do, so i can achive my goal of every time the year changes it change the number from "2012######" to "2013######"